# iPhone - Validating USA city and state

Tags: iphone, validation, state, city

In my app, i've two text fields where user can enter city and state.
I want to validate whether city entered is within the state entered.
The app is targeted for USA people only. So is there any way to validate the city and state details?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Google Maps API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html) and Check for Location.

So you don't have to maintain an extensive list and are always up to date.

Comment: I am aware of google maps API. But I don't know which webservice exactly to be used.

Answer (score -1):

I can think of using a `nsdictionary` with `nsarray` of cities and with state as the key. Once the user enters the state and city, you can get the array of objects using the state as the key and compare the entered city with the objects in the returned array.

Comment: That will be really difficult to maintain all the list of cities in dictionary. Also one may not be aware of all the major cities/towns in USA.